# Creating custom python docker images

Tags: python, docker

I have a python code for which I want to create a docker image. Now as per my understanding we need a `Dockerfile` and our python code `code.py`. Inside a `Dockerfile` we need to write:

```
FROM python:3

ADD code.py /

RUN pip3 install imapclient

CMD [ "python", "./code.py" ]
```

My first question is about this `Dockerfile`. First we have mentioned `FROM python:3` because we want to use `python3`. Next we have added our code. In `RUN` we can write a dependency of our code. So for example if our code need python package `imapclient` we can mention it here so that it will be installed before docker file is build. But what if our code do not have any requirements.? **Is this line `RUN` important. Can we exclude it when we don't need it.?**

So now let's say we have finally created our docker image `python-hello-world` by using command `docker build -t python-hello-world .`. I can see it using command `docker images -a`. Now when I do `docker ps`, it is not listed there because the container is not running. Now to start it, I'll have to do `docker run python-hello-world`. This will start the code. But I want it to be running always in the background like a Linux service. How to do that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this line RUN important? Can we exclude it when we don't need it?

**Yes if your code doesn't need the packages then you can exclude it.**

But I want it to be running always in the background like a Linux service. How to do that?

If you want to run it as background then use below command.

```
docker run -d --restart=always python-hello-world
```

This will start container in background and will start automatically when system reboots.

Comment: I actually used `--restart` flag but didnt used -d so it gave me an error. Well thanks. One more question, when we use docker build command why we use `.` at the end

Comment: . referes to current directory in linux, docker build . means its using dockerfile present in current directory

Comment: And if we are running the command from another directory we need to give path instead of `.` .?